# PouchDB in an Electron app gives error "dbFactory is not a function"

Tags: pouchdb

> levelup.js?006c:115Uncaught TypeError: dbFactory is not a function

This is my question.
I use it in chrome, but it's ok.
When I use it in electron (Vue2.0), the same, but give me this tip.
Who can help me?

Comment: same here... =(

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue and couldn't resolve it. Here's some documentation: https://github.com/nolanlawson/hello-electron-with-pouchdb. The author says that an alternate solution is to use the browser version of pouchdb, which ultimately worked for me.

Example:

```
import PouchDB from 'pouchdb-browser'

const db = new PouchDB('testdb', {adapter: 'websql'});
```

Docs: https://pouchdb.com/adapters.html

Answer (score 0):

Try to use init PouchDB as

```
const PouchDB = require('electron').remote.require('pouchdb');
```